# Calculating large exponential probabilities

Tags: probability, algorithms, approximation

Earlier today there was [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4k5NGUjTWs) attempting to solve a problem for a certain game. In it he tries to calculate the probability of certain events happening which narrows down to this equation:

$P(r) = 1-(1-10^{-1014})^{10^{155}}$

Unfortunately, there isn't a trivial way to calculate the percentage form of the answer due to very large exponents, even with a machine. This is why he was unable to come up with an percentage himself.

**So how does one approximate or calculate a percent form of large exponent probabilities similar to this ?**

*Correction*: The original value I posted was $P(r) = (1-10^{-1014})^{10^{155}}$, this was different the the actual formula used in the video which has been corrected to the one above, but doesn't effect the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 
$$
(1-10^{-1014})^{10^{155}}
= e^{10^{155}\ln(1-10^{-1014})}
\simeq 
e^{-10^{155}\cdot 10^{-1014}}
=
e^{-10^{-859}}
\simeq 1-10^{-859}
$$
using the low-order Taylor expansions $\ln(1+u) = u +o(u)$ and $e^u = 1+u+o(u)$ when $u\to 0$.

Another approach, using $(1+u)^n =  1+nu + o(u)$ for fixed $n$ and $u\to 0$ (which is a valid approximation as $"nu" = 10^{155}\cdot 10^{-1014} \ll 1$) gives directly
$$
(1-10^{-1014})^{10^{155}}
\simeq 1+ 10^{155}\cdot (-10^{-1014})
=
1-10^{-859}.
$$
*(the second approach is faster, but a bit more dangerous, as for the approximation you need to argue or "feel" that your $n$ can be considered as a constant w.r.t. your $u$).*

Comment: Ah, Taylor expansions to the rescue! Thanks!

Comment: Story of my life.

Comment: @ClementC. Did I confess that I felt in love with Taylor expansions about 62 years ago and that I am as fascinated by them as I was on the first day ? Cheers.